# Convert an NSArray of strings to an NSArray of ints

Tags: nsstring, nsarray, int

I have an NSArray of strings, like so:

```
NSString *numbers = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
NSArray *numberArray = [numbers componentsSeperatedByString:@" "];
```

I want to convert this entire array of string numbers into ints.
How can I do so?

Comment: Look up the "for loop" in a C reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can't store an array of `int`'s (which are raw C types) in a NSArray (which expect Objective C objects) directly, you need to stuff these "`int`" values into "`NSNumber`" objects.

You can do this via:

```
NSMutableArray * newNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: [numberArray count]];
for(NSString * numberString in numberArray)
{
    NSNumber * trueNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [numberString integerValue]];
    [newNumberArray addObject: trueNumber];
}
```

Comment: you missed an opening bracket: `[NSMutableArray alloc]...` should be `[[NSMutableArray alloc]...`